# Setting a static route for a specific network adapter with two network adapters

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I have a virtual windows server 2008 r2 with 2 virtual network adapters, one is part of a domain and the other isn't. When I ping to a specific PC that is part of the domain it connects to it through the second network adapter (the one that isn't in the domain) and I tried to change that with a static route:

```
ROUTE ADD -P <target PC's IP> MASK <Subnet mask from ipconfig> <Default Gateway of the adapter in the domain> if <tried it with all possible interfaces>
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work, so I'll be happy to be assisted with **How to make this static route so my server will connect to the PC that is in the domain through the network adapter that is in the domain?**

Output of route print and ipconfig:

```
C:\Users\user>route print

========================================

Interface List

 18...00 15 5d 80 0f 47 ......Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter #2

 11...00 15 5d 80 0f 1a ......Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter

  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1

 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter

 21...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2

IPv4 Route Table

=========================================================================== 

Active Routes: Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway    Interface  Metric

          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0  192.168.128.254   192.168.128.13      5

          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.137.1   192.168.137.15      5

        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

    192.168.128.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.128.13    261

   192.168.128.13  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.128.13    261

  192.168.128.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.128.13    261

    192.168.137.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.137.15    261

   192.168.137.15  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.137.15    261

  192.168.137.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.137.15    261

        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.128.13    261

        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.137.15    261

  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.128.13    261

  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.137.15    261

=========================================================================== 
Persistent Routes:   

Network Address       Netmask  Gateway Address Metric

192.168.128.8       255.255.255.0  192.168.128.254    1

===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table

=========================================================================== 

Active Routes:

 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway

 18    261 ::/0                     fe80::f427:d7d8:4ec2:fd5

  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link

 11    261 fe80::/64                On-link

 18    261 fe80::/64                On-link

 11    261 fe80::8ce7:a7a5:d7c0:faf1/128 On-link

 18    261 fe80::a8c7:ee26:b1bb:fd77/128 On-link

  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link

 11    261 ff00::/8                 On-link

 18    261 ff00::/8                 On-link

===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:   None

C:\Users\user>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a8c7:ee26:b1bb:fd77%18

   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.15

   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::f427:d7d8:4ec2:fd5%18

                                       192.168.137.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domainName.com

   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8ce7:a7a5:d7c0:faf1%11

   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.128.13    

   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.128.254

Tunnel adapter isatap.domainName.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domainName.com

Tunnel adapter isatap.{5364A7C9-95AE-4753-98A3-8D60A49D43D5}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Comment: please provide output of ROUTE PRINT and IPCONFIG

Comment: Added output - don't have enough reputation for images yet...

Comment: Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected - Start by connecting the network adapter in question to the network.

Comment: As far as I understand the part of Tunnel adapter is for IPv6 (isn't it?) and the server is connected to the network - both of the domain and outside it.

Comment: @Moshisho Yeah, your network adapters are reported as connected. You're not using the Tunnel adapter in this set up but Windows insist on telling you all about it.

Comment: My bad. I read the info wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you have 2 DEFAULT GATEWAY which violates the meaning of DEFAULT GATEWAY. Put the default gateway only on one interface. Then with static route, direct the traffic you want to go via the other interface.

For example, LAN1 192.168.123.13 Mask 255.255.255.0 and GW 192.168.128.254. That will get all traffic to 192.168.123.x and anything to any other network will be directed through the gateway.

But then add LAN2 192.168.137.15 Mask 255.255.255.0 WITHOUT any default gateway. That will automatically create a routing entry that 192.168.137.x will go through this interface instead of the Default Gateway. Now, if you want other traffic to go through that interface, you can create a static route like:

ROUTE ADD -P 192.168.33.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.137.1

That will send the traffic going to 192.168.33.x through LAN2 as 192.168.137.1 is in the same network as LAN2 interface.

Comment: Where did you get the 33 for the `route` command? I'm having what seems to be a similar problem over [here](https://serverfault.com/q/865853/218519).

Comment: @InteXX - `192.168.33.x` is just an arbitrary example subnet. Replace that and the mask with whatever network you want to add a static route for.

Comment: The 2nd NIC is `192.168.3.x` and the gateway is on the same subnet as the 1st NIC, `192.168.2.1`. My route command is `ROUTE ADD 192.168.3.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.1 IF 19`, and it still doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: @InteXX Not sure what you are attempting to do. If your 2nd NIC is 3.x then why would you want to route 3.x via the 1st NIC's gateway? Maybe you do want that, but then why having the 2nd NIC in the first place?

Comment: It's all pretty well laid out [here](https://serverfault.com/q/865853/218519). I've tried just about everything I can think of, but nothing seems to work. I'm clearly missing something somewhere. Surely this is a fairly standard configuration/requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately the [Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/865853/218519) has fallen off the top of the list. It's no longer getting attention, but the issue is still hurting us. Could you weigh in with your opinion? Is routing the way to go with this? Is my route correct?